# GPG does not accept passphrase that begins with some special characters

Tags: python, gnupg

I want to encrypt a word with a passphrase but if my passphrase starts with some special characters (eg. -, '), the encryption doesn't work.

I did

```
passphrase = getpass("Please put your passphrase: ")
command2 = ["gpg", "--symmetric", "--armor", "--pinentry-mode=loopback", "--passphrase", f"{passphrase}"]
out2 = subprocess.check_output(command2, input=plaintext, universal_newlines=False)
```

If I type -d as my passphrase, I get

```
gpg: conflicting commands
```

or if I type -hello, I get a lot worse message.

All I want is I want gpg to recognise my passphrase as string not an unix argument and reads it whether it starts with a special character or not.

Is there a way of doing that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `--passphrase foo`, write it like `--passphrase=foo`:

```
import subprocess

plaintext='this is a test'.encode()
passphrase = input("Please put your passphrase: ")
command2 = [
    "gpg",
    "--symmetric",
    "--armor",
    "--pinentry-mode=loopback",
    f"--passphrase={passphrase}",
]
out2 = subprocess.check_output(command2, input=plaintext, universal_newlines=False)
print(out2.decode())
```

Running this produces:

```
Please put your passphrase: -secret-
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

jA0ECQMKlfSRKyXHYEr/0kIBuXUN62boDFLMd/OJjWM2OFvnFC9pTuze607X6kRg
jUivjnuSbePZFh5eEkBV+fGo9CvUI84SdUgq47sw+0CcXgI=
=lZHg
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```